try-catch: My question is: when an error happens in my try-block, the catch-block handles it, but the rest of the program crashes
The issue is that when an exception occurs in the try block, the catch block handles it flawlessly, but after managing it, the application crashes, which is the primary objective of the try-catch blocks.
My issue is that when my code is executed, the first two lines of code execute perfectly, and an exception occurs on the third line, which is well handled by the catch block. However, I expected that after it handles the exception, it will run the fourth and fifth lines of code, preventing my application from crashing, but it did not execute the fourth and fifth lines of code after handling the exception

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review the guidelines for [ask] a good question, and in particular, what makes a [mre]. RIght now there's not really enough information to answer this, and it risks being closed as needing debugging details or clarity.

You seem to be misunderstanding how try/catches work, but it's hard to be sure without clearer code examples.

After an exception thrown, the catch block is executed and the code continue after the all try and catch block.
Line 0 // start try
Line 1 // executed
Line 2 // executed
Line 3 // Error
Line 4 // not invoke
Line 5 // not invoke
Line 6 // end try
Line 7 // start catch
Line 8 // invoke
Line 9 // end catch
Line 10 // invoke
…

To solve it, you can move your 4,5 lines to be after line 10.
But it really depend on your purpose, please share piece of code to help you decide the correct way
